# Loop de DIV's em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Estou gerando um loop de uma div de tamanho fixo e gostaria que na hora da impressão cada uma fique em uma página.
Porém a primeira Div do Loop fica com uma `margem-top` impedindo que isso aconteça !
Existe alguma maneira que faça essa primeira div ser dirente das demais nessa questão da `margin` ?
Segue Código para melhor entendimento
Grato :)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .papel {width: 297mm;height: 208mm; background-color:red;border: 3px solid gray;top: -45%;left: 0%;position: absolute; overflow:hidden;transform:scale(0.5) translate3d(0px,0px,0px); margin-bottom: 80px;float:left;}
    @media print {
        .papel {transform:scale(1); margin-top:0!important; border:none;top:0px!important;left: 0px!important;transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)!important;}
        #imprimir{display:none!important;}
    }
</style>
<?php for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++):
        if($i == 1) $cor = "blue";
        if($i == 2) $cor = "black";
        if($i == 3) $cor = "yellow";
        if($i == 4) $cor = "green";
    ?>
    <div class="papel" id="papel" style="margin-top:calc(210mm * <?php echo $i?>)!important;background-color:<?php echo $cor ?>">
    </div>
<?php endfor;?>

<input type="button" id="imprimir" onclick="imprimir()" value="Imprimir">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imprimir(){
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você quer div para cima? não saia inserindo por baixo é isso?

Comment: @KingRider  Ao clicar no botão imprimir, é possível notar que a ultima pagina esta em branco. Gostaria de remove-la. Acredito que seja por alguma gafe no loop. Editei a questão para melhor compreensão. Obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar o seletor `:first-child` do css. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.minha_div{
   background-color:red;
   color:white;
   display:block;
   margin-top:5px;
   padding:2px;
   text-align:center;
}

.minha_div:first-child{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="minha_div">
   <b>DIV 1</b>
</div>
<div class="minha_div">
   <b>DIV 2</b>
 </div>
<div class="minha_div">
   <b>DIV 3</b>
 </div>
<div class="minha_div">
   <b>DIV 4</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se já esta no `loop`, basta verificar qual é a primeira posição com um `IF`:

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++): ?>

  <?php if($i == 1): ?>
    // Faz o que precisa na primeira posição
    <div class="papel" id="papel" style="margin-top:calc(105mm * <?php echo $i?>)!important;">
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

    // Demais posições
    <div class="papel" id="papel" style="margin-top:calc(105mm * <?php echo $i?>)!important;">
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Não alterei a `div` pois não sei o que quer fazer nelas, mas basta montar as `divs` e deixar neste formato o `loop`.

Espero que ajude, qualquer dúvida pergunte.

Att;

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio ! Consegui realizar o que queria, alterei o codigo para melhor compreensão... Seria possivel tirar esses espaços brancos antes da impressão?  Pois na impressão eles não aparecem =s

Comment: Espaço em branco?

Comment: Caso a tenha respondido sua pergunta marque como resposta

Answer (score 0):

Se o primeiro elemento não tiver problema com `margin-top` igual a `0 (zero)`, inicie o incrementador `$i` com ele:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++): ?>
    <div class="papel" id="papel" style="margin-top:calc(105mm * <?php echo $i?>)!important;">
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Dica: Ao utilizar blocos estruturais com `PHP` mesclado ao `HTML`, há uma *[sintaxe alternativa](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)*, como usado acima no `for`, que facilita a leitura do código.

Comment: não entendi, você abriu um bloco `for` e fechou com `foreach`?

Comment: Editei e corrigi para `endfor`.